# Android text views in a circular UI design without library

Tags: android, android-circularview

I saw there is a [library](https://github.com/sababado/CircularView) for CircularView. I am trying to do the UI design with Relative and Framelayouts as follows without using any libraries. Also, I want to perform the click actions on each text view(1, 2, 3, 4, and 5), and based on the click the arrow should update accordingly.

[image]

is there any better way to achieve this without using any library?

Comment: Its possible with `ConstrintLayout`. search for Circular Positioning in `ConstrintLayout` . But there is line indicators which be tricky to create . better use a Custom View .

Comment: Yeah on click should work for the text views 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 also. We can have 5 different images but the click won't work in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I achieved it with the help of Relative and Linear layouts. Also handling the click actions based on the view which are in invisible mode. Here I kept an image view I used 5 different types of images updating it based on the clicks.

For example,

> if the user clicks on the number 1 then updating the image with speed1 with an arrow towards the 1, and

> if the user clicks on the number 2 then updating the image with speed2 with an arrow towards the 2

and so on...

so here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deviceName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
            tools:text="Master bedroom fan" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivDots"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_4"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dots_horizontal"
            android:tint="@color/color_black"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/currentSpeedIV"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLL"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/speed1"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonRL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLL"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/threeLL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-35dp"
            android:elevation="@dimen/dp_2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/three" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/vertical_line" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="@dimen/dp_100"
                android:rotation="90"
                android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
                android:tint="@color/blue"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonFL"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ellipse_bg"
            android:src="@drawable/ellipse"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/twoLL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/threeLL"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonFL"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/two" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:rotation="90"
                android:text="@string/vertical_line" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
                android:tint="@color/blue"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fourLL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/threeLL"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonFL"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
                android:tint="@color/blue"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:rotation="90"
                android:text="@string/vertical_line" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/four" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fiveLL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fourLL"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fourLL"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
                android:tint="@color/blue"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:rotation="90"
                android:text="@string/vertical_line" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/five" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/oneLL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/twoLL"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonFL"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/one" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:rotation="90"
                android:text="@string/vertical_line" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
                android:tint="@color/blue"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/turnOnOffIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonRL"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonRL"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonRL"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_50"
        android:src="@drawable/switch_on"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/currentSpeedIV"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/decreaseTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:text="@string/minus"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/sp_30"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/speedTV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_30"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/wind_speed" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/increaseTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:text="@string/plus"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```